# Rendering components using .map resets setTimeout within components

Tags: reactjs, settimeout

I've built a 'repeater' component that accepts a component to repeat as a prop. There are add, remove, and clear functions to add or remove an instance, or to clear all instances.

I'm trying to use this repeater component to render another component that has a setTimeout inside it. If you add or remove another component, all other components' setTimouts are reset, and so they all fire at the exact same time.

The repeater component I'm using:

```
class Repeater extends React.Component {
  state = {
    elements: [],
  };

  component = Notification; // For simplicity - actually dynamic from props
  count = 0;

  getKey = () => {
    return this.count++;
  };

  add = props => {
    const { elements } = this.state;    
    props.key = this.getKey();
    elements.push(props);

    this.setState({ elements });
  };

  remove = key => {
    const { elements } = this.state;
    const newElements = elements.filter(element => {
      return element.key !== key;
    });

    this.setState({ elements: newElements });
  };

  clear = () => {
    this.setState({ elements: [] });
  };

  render() {
    const { elements } = this.state;
    const Component = this.component;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {elements.map(element => {
          return <Component key={element.key} {...element} />;
        })}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

The component I'm rendering:

```
export function Notification() {
  const {
    isOpen = true,
    message,
    title,
    duration = 4.5,
  } = props;
  const [openState, setOpenState] = React.useState(isOpen);
  let timer;

  const clearTimer = () => {
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
  };

 const handleClose = () => {
    clearTimer();
    console.log('Test');
  };

  const setTimer = () => {
    if (duration) timer = setTimeout(() => handleClose(), duration * 1000);
  };

  if (openState) {
    setTimer();
    return (
      <div
        onMouseEnter={() => clearTimer()}
        onMouseLeave={() => setTimer()}>
        <div>
          <Icon />
        </div>
        <div>{title}</div>
        <div>{message}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: can u provide code ?

Comment: No code. No chocolates!

Comment: @Andre C Please mention Code to understand the problem.

Comment: Apologies all, hit submit preemptively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the .map function is an issue in this case. You need to render each component individually otherwise that map function will run every time an update is triggered and reset the elements to their initial state.

I updated the solution to use the latest ES6+ features. There's still things left to be desired from the functionality that you want to achieve and the full context of your code, but here's a first iteration that should work since the setState functions are referencing the previous state.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export function Notification({ duration=4500, isOpen=true, message, title }) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(isOpen);

  let timer;

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimer();
  });

  const handleClose = () => {
    clearTimer();
  };

  const clearTimer = () => {
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
  };

  const setTimer = () => {
    timer = setTimeout(() => handleClose(), duration);
  };

  if (!open) return null;

  return (
    <div
      onMouseEnter={() => clearTimer()}
      onMouseLeave={() => setTimer()}>
      <div>
        <Icon />
      </div>
      <div>{title}</div>
      <div>{message}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export function Repeater({ component }) {
  const [elements, setElements] = useState([]);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const Component = component ? component : Notification;

  const getKey = () => {
    setCount(count => count + 1);
    return count;
  };

  const add = (props) => {
    setElements((elements) => elements.push({ ...props, key: getKey }));
  };

  const remove = (key) => {
    setElements((elements) => elements.filter((e) => e.key !== key));
  };

  const clear = () => {
    setElements([]);
  };

  const renderedElements = elements.map(({ key, ...rest }) => (
    <Component key={key} {...rest} />
  ));

  return (
    <>
      {renderedElements}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Any way of achieving what I'm trying to achieve using a Component for the repeater? I need to initiate it with a ref prop... Edit: this is to access the methods from outside (call xyz.add) to add a new notification etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by storing the render time of the notification component in state on first load, and finding the difference between it and the current time in my setTimer method.

```
...

const [renderTime] = React.useState(Date.now());

...

const setTimer = () => {
  if (duration) {
    const elapsed = Date.now() - openTime;
    const timeout = duration - elapsed;
    timer = setTimeout(() => handleClose(), timeout);
  }
};
```